# Show images on dashboard

Tags: php, laravel

I explain a little about the context of the problem. Create an application in Laravel 9 and how my application works: The user purchases a package and at the time of purchase they are given the option to send proof of payment through a modal. That image of that payment receipt should be seen in a view that I have for an administrator user where he can see that image that the user uploaded but I don't know how to do it, it already worked for me but it stops working, I'll share how I have configured filesystems file:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => true,
        ],
```

This is the method that validates and saves the image:

```
public function uploadPaymentProof(Request $request, Service $service)
    {
        // Validaciones
        $request->validate([
            
            'proof' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048', // Ajusta las validaciones según tus necesidades
        ]);

        

        // Obtiene el archivo
        $proof = $request->file('proof');
        //Codigo ingresado por el usuario
        $code = $request->input('code');
        
      
        // Almacena el archivo en el sistema de archivos público
        $path = $proof->store('public/app/public'); 
       
        // Asignación de campos para crear una nueva solicitud de servicio
    $serviceRequest = new ServiceRequest();
    $serviceRequest->user_id = auth()->id(); // Asigna el ID del usuario actual
    $serviceRequest->service_id = $service->id; // Asigna el ID del servicio
    $serviceRequest->payment_proof_path = $path; // Asigna la ruta del comprobante de pago
    $serviceRequest->code = $code; // Asigna el código ingresado por el usuario
    $serviceRequest->status = 'pendiente'; // Asigna el estado, puede ser 'pendiente' o el valor deseado

    // Guarda la solicitud en la base de datos
    $serviceRequest->save();

 // Redirección a la página de inicio del dashboard o a donde sea necesario
return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', 'Comprobante de pago subido con éxito');  
}
```

and this is the part that should show the image:

```
<!-- Muestra la imagen del comprobante de pago en el modal -->
                <img src="{{ Storage::url($request->payment_proof_path) }}" alt="Comprobante de Pago" class="img-fluid">
```

I tried what I show you in the code but it doesn't work properly for me.

Comment: When you try to open view with those images what type of error do you get? Is it showing "404" status in developer tools?

Comment: No, only the url is not generated correctly, it points me to another address that is not configured

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that the symbolic link is not being created correctly in my path. When I execute the php artisan storage:Link command, a text type file is created with the name storage. I already deleted cache, I already cleaned everything and it's still the same, I don't understand what it could be